# How can I extract data from complex JSON file with reactJS?

Tags: json, reactjs, jsx

I am new to reactJS. I have a JSON file which looks like this:

[image: Json file]

I want to extract data and display each post with its comments, user who commented and created time and display it with JSX using the map function.
So I declared an empty array called items in my state and put all these data into it and tried to browse it but I got this error:

> ×
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

this is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World !!!! </h1>
      <ul>
        { this.state.items.comments.data.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.data[item].from.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that comments is itself an array of object i figured out the solution and thank you any way

Comment: Images of text are not searchable, or accessible. Please [edit] the question to augment the image with the JSON it contains or better yet replace it with an [mre] of the JSON it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I have to use map inside another map because I have an array in another array and this code solved the problem:

```
render{
  return (
    <div>
        {
          this.state.items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <h4>{item.id}</h4>
                <ul>
                  {
                    item.comments.data.map((data) => {
                      return (
                          <li>
                            {data.message} :  {data.created_time} : {{data.from.name}
                          </li>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </ul>
              </div>
            );
          })
        } 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice to meet you.
I can solve it.
Please do like below.

```
render() {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Hello World !!!! </h1>
  <ul>
    { this.state.items.comments.data.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.from.name}</li>)}
  </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Please reply with your opinion.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

in your json file look like you get array of array
try with this hope this will work

```
this.state.items.map((item,index)=>{
    this.state.items[item].comments.data.map(element=>
        <li key={item.id}>{item.from.name}</li>)
    })
})
```

Comment: The problem is that comments is itself an array of object i figured out the solution and thank you any way